# How to copy only data of list, not the reference

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create **List of List of int** in Dart but having some problem.

1. If a List of int listInt = [1,2,3] is made and added to main List(List of List of int), it is added successfully.
   [[1,2,3]]
2. Now if I clear listInt **listInt.clear()** and add new values **listInt = [3,2,1]** which is then followed by adding that into main list again; it is added but it also overwrites the previous one.
   **[[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]**
3. What i want is **[[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]]**

Code is as follows

```
    List<int> listInt = List();
    List<List<int>> mainListInt = List();
    listInt.add(1);
    listInt.add(2);
    listInt.add(3);
    mainListInt.add(listInt);
    print(mainListInt);
    listInt.clear();
    print(mainListInt);
    listInt.add(3);
    listInt.add(2);
    listInt.add(1);
    mainListInt.add(listInt);
    print(mainListInt);
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[]]
[[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you do not save the reference of your sublist to your main list as this will apply edits to your sub list as you noticed.
You can create a new instance using [`List.of`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/List/List.of.html) (it creates a copy of your list, which is a different reference):

```dart
mainListInt.add(List.of(listInt));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listInt.toList()` to create copy of the list.

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  List<int> listInt = List();
  List<List<int>> mainListInt = List();
  listInt.add(1);
  listInt.add(2);
  listInt.add(3);
  mainListInt.add(listInt.toList());
  print(mainListInt);
  listInt.clear();
  print(mainListInt);
  listInt.add(3);
  listInt.add(2);
  listInt.add(1);
  mainListInt.add(listInt.toList());
  print(mainListInt);
}
```

Comment: That is a shortcut to `List.from`.

Comment: This is a independent method. Naturally, any algorithm has an implementation and it does not matter in which place it is implemented. Are you hinting that this method is overkill?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to say there with the algorithm part, but no to the question. You can look at [the implementation of `List.toList`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html) - it uses `List.from`.

Comment: Yeah... You did not answer my question. `Are you hinting that this method is overkill?` Even if the algorithm implemented in ` List.from()` but not directly in this method. What is wrong to use `Iterable.toList()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
ListDestination = List.from(ListOrigin);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// 'list1' contains [1, 2]
var list1 = [1, 2];
// 'list2' contains [1, 2]
var list2 = [...list1];// here we are copying only data and note reference
    list2.add(56); // 'list2' contains [1, 2,56]
// 'list2' contains [1, 2,56]
    print(list1); // this won't add 56 bcs List not reference to it 
    print(list2);// it will display 56
```

Answer (score -1):

One solution that i have found but not like it is using List.generate() for specific number for lists within a list.

```
    List<List<int>> mainListInt = List.generate(2, (i) => []);
    mainListInt[0].add(1);
    mainListInt[0].add(2);
    mainListInt[0].add(3);
    print(mainListInt);
    mainListInt[1].add(3);
    mainListInt[1].add(2);
    mainListInt[1].add(1);
    print(mainListInt);
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 3], []]
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]]
```